# Google play console STILL does not show line numbers in my C++ native code

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, build.gradle, google-play-console

I added the following to my build.gradle file in order to have debug line information added to my native C++ code in my signed bundle file.

```
ndk
{
   debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL'
}
```

This was added to android.buildTypes.release

I analyzed the generated signed aab file and it looks like it included the correct symbol files:

[image: AAB symbol files]

However when I get a crash, the Google Play Console STILL refuses to show line numbers. I am vexed as to why this is.

I am making calls from Java into a C++ method. Maybe that is why it doesn't show line numbers?
I am using the correct gradle version for the debugSymbolLevel to work. Despite all this I am NOT getting line numbers in Google Play Console for the stack trace. Any ideas why this could be happening? I greatly appreciate any help on this.

Below is the example:

```
`*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 28273 >>> com.venumspyder.kingdomdash <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x00000000004abf08  /data/app/~~dmghSQnMdgAN4oDgZSaM5A==/com.venumspyder.kingdomdash-t1j7ELp2ucNTTypyQuV8Bw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libkingdomdash.so (**Java_com_venumspyder_kingdomdash_KingdomDashLib_ProcessProductDetails+849**)
  #01  pc 0x0000000000039738  /data/app/~~dmghSQnMdgAN4oDgZSaM5A==/com.venumspyder.kingdomdash-t1j7ELp2ucNTTypyQuV8Bw==/oat/arm64/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline+200)
  #02  pc 0x00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568)
  #03  pc 0x00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228)
  #04  pc 0x0000000000318290  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376)
  #05  pc 0x000000000030e5bc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+996)
  #06  pc 0x000000000067f8bc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+548)
  #07  pc 0x000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #08  pc 0x000000000038f928  /data/app/~~dmghSQnMdgAN4oDgZSaM5A==/com.venumspyder.kingdomdash-t1j7ELp2ucNTTypyQuV8Bw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.venumspyder.kingdomdash.KingdomDashBillingUpdateListener.OnQueryProductDetailsSuccess+72)
  #09  pc 0x0000000000683648  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+1344)
  #10  pc 0x0000000000131594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20)
  #11  pc 0x000000000038a280  /data/app/~~dmghSQnMdgAN4oDgZSaM5A==/com.venumspyder.kingdomdash-t1j7ELp2ucNTTypyQuV8Bw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (com.venumspyder.kingdomdash.BillingManager$1.onProductDetailsResponse+36)
  #12  pc 0x000000000067e63c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1808)
  #13  pc 0x000000000012da14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
  #14  pc 0x000000000039ad40  /data/app/~~dmghSQnMdgAN4oDgZSaM5A==/com.venumspyder.kingdomdash-t1j7ELp2ucNTTypyQuV8Bw==/oat/arm64/base.vdex (g1.p.call+556)
  #15  pc 0x0000000000305bb8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.11207139950870688243)+268)
  #16  pc 0x000000000066b67c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+780)
  #17  pc 0x000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88)
  #18  pc 0x000000000026dbe8  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run+200)
  #19  pc 0x00000000002d0638  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker+984)
  #20  pc 0x00000000002cd650  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run+64)
  #21  pc 0x0000000000176798  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+72)
  #22  pc 0x0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #23  pc 0x00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #24  pc 0x0000000000555830  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+460)
  #25  pc 0x00000000005a3fb8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1308)
  #26  pc 0x00000000000da278  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #27  pc 0x000000000007a448  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)`
```

I followed the instructions as outlined in: [text](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code#native-crash-support)

Despite this I do not get line numbers showing up in the Google Play Console.

Thanks to anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Comment: BTW I decided to add the following to my gradle file: android {
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393". Perhaps that will help?